# Android listview searching french words

Tags: java, android

I am filling a listview with french words, some of these words contains special characters ( for example : vidéo contains "é" ).

I also have an edittext which I use to search these words, what I want is that when I write for example video ("e" instead of "é"), the same word will appear in the listview. And the same rule must be applied on all words

Can I do it ?

Comment: Yes, you can. you need a database. A table with the correct words, with a unique id per each word. And a table with "similar words" with the same id of the correct word.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of SQlite Database store all the words into the database by giving the same ids for such words so that when you try to retreive, the words with all that corresponding id come up...

Comment: Well Karan I though of that, but the response time will be slow because I want to use it in a search process